# How to get childrenIndexes of a node in Angular Google Charts (OrgChart)?

Tags: angular, google-visualization, orgchart, angular-google-chart

I am using angular google charts to draw an org chart. Everything works fine, but I cannot use the method getChildrenIndexes(row) of the library. If anyone can help me with a way to get child indexes of a selected node? For reference, I am following [this](https://github.com/FERNman/angular-google-charts) repo.

Comment: you can use the method during the select event. will you please share your code? it would be easier to provide a solution...

Comment: @WhiteHat I was able to resolve the issue, thank you anyways! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to resolve the issue and will post the answer for the people who might face the same issue.

My HTML looks like this,

```
<google-chart #chart [title]="title" [type]="type" [data]="data" [columns]="columnNames" [options]="options" (select)="onSelect($event)">
</google-chart>
```

My component.ts

```
export class EditorComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('chart') chart;
  onSelect(event): void{
    console.log(this.chart.chart.
        getChildrenIndexes(event.selection[0].row));
  }
}
```